# Options not creating from jinja template

Tags: html, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to enlist users in a table, and select them in 3 select forms.
I've given proper placeholder value in flask app; the same (for row in rows) works for table in the same page, but the "options" are not loading. What's the workaround?

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="select1" class="form-label mt-4">pref1</label>
                            <select name="select1" class="form-select">
                                <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                                {% for row in rows %}
                                    <option value="{{ row.id }}">{{ row.user }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv9oW.png)

I've manually put options, it works. My sqlite command runs ok.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using a generator that you have to convert into a list in order to iterate over it several times? `list(rows)`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: list entities are loaded in table, just above this code. I used the same {% for row in rows %} block to iterate and create <options>. This is the problem, no options are being created. @Detlef

Comment: @shamayel As I wrote, your database query may return a generator that you can only use once. On the second attempt it no longer delivers any results. You can get around this by converting the result of your query into a list that allows you to go through it multiple times. However, it is only a guess as your presented code shows very little of your efforts.

Comment: Thank you very much @Detlef ! And yes, I'm non-CS, novice therefore. Just trying to make a full-stack stuff.